# Programmatically Copy Files from 'Temporary Internet Files' into other directory

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I need to copy all images from Temperary Internet Files to some other directory. I tried using  below code

```
string[] IeImageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache).ToString());
```

the problem is that GetFiles method returns only few files. Whereas I can see many files in the same folder when I browse through internet explorer 'View Files'(IE options -> General Tab -> Settings ->Temporary internet Files).

I need to know the physical path so as to query the directory and get the files. How to achieve that. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files you see when you do 'View Files' (IE options > General Tab > Settings > Temporary internet Files) are not actually files that are located on disc directly in the `Temporary Internet Files` folder.

There's a hidden folder inside that location called `Content.IE5`, and that will contain several randomly named folders with the actual temporary internet files inside them.

To get a list of them you can do this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache),
    "Content.IE5");
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

For more information check out [A Primer on Temporary Internet Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/19/wininet-temporary-internet-files-cache-and-explorer-folder-view.aspx) by Eric Law.

Comment: I am getting error as "Access denied". Error: "Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\[User Name]\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\INetCache\\Content.IE5' is denied."