# How to copy file from Temporary Internet file folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some temporary files  in `Temporary Internet file folder`  i need copy them to my folder,i see the file in folder but function `File.Exists` no.

My function

```
  string InternetTempPath= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
  string TempFilePath = Path.Combine(InternetTempPath, "MyFile.pdf");
  bool Isfile = System.IO.File.Exists(TempFilePath);
```

don't see the files that i am looking for.

**Files in `Temporary Internet file folder` do not have names they can't even be renamed,I think i need to look files by Internet Adress,or Last Checked.They not like ordinary files.**

How can i find this files?

Comment: Are you trying to copy a file from a client machines temporary Internet file folder to the server machine?

Comment: You are missing extension of your file in `Path.Combine` method.

Comment: No it is on my local pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a hidden folder inside that location called Content.IE5, and that will contain several randomly named folders with the actual temporary internet files inside them.

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache),
    "Content.IE5");
```

[Here is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581094/programmatically-copy-files-from-temporary-internet-files-into-other-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the file extension?
Your file is probably "MyfileName.txt" not just "MyfileName".
Try adding the file extension and seeing if that works...

```
string TempFilePath= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
TempFilePath+="MyfileName.txt";
bool Isfile = System.IO.File.Exists(TempFilePath);
```

P.S. appending strings is not recommended in C# the way you're using +=. If these were normal strings I'd recommend using a StringBuilder to combine them, as you're dealing with Paths, try using Path.Combine:

```
string TempFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), "MyfileName.txt");
bool Isfile = System.IO.File.Exists(TempFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You need to add backward slash after the Temparary internet folder path.

```
TempFilePath += "\\myfile.txt";
```

**Solution 2:** (Recommended)

You can use `Path.Combine()` to combine the paths as below:

```
string newpath = Path.Combine(TempFilePath,"myfile.txt");
```

Comment: :) i know,path is wright.Problem in some think else

Comment: @user3567884: are you using extension of file in the program, because your posted code does not have the extension.

Comment: Files in Temporary Internet file folder do not have hames they can't even be renamed,I think i need to look files by Internet Adress

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the miss of slashes. You should use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of concatenating the file path yourself:

```
string TempFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
string filePath = Path.Combine(TempFilePath, "MyfileName");
bool Isfile = System.IO.File.Exists(filePath);
```