# Can I copy a image from Internet Explorer's cache loaded by WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, image, internet-explorer, browser, temporary-files

I read if I've displayed a image in the webBrowser then I've already downloaded it so I could get it from Internet Explorer tmp files. Is it even possible? if so, any C# code example how to do tgis? I looked at `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)` folder but I can't find any image there. Not sure if it's right path. It could save a lot of time sice the image will be downloaded just once.

Comment: i wouldn't depend on it - its an internal directory structure and might get cleared at any time.

Comment: Even before I close application where WebBrowser is used?

Comment: yep. ie can set its own rules.

Comment: can't I force it to be deleted when I want to?

Comment: of course, but the rug might get pulled away from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [c# - Programmatically Copy Files from 'Temporary Internet Files' into other directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581094/programmatically-copy-files-from-temporary-internet-files-into-other-directory)

below sample code

```
        //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581094/programmatically-copy-files-from-temporary-internet-files-into-other-directory
        var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), "Content.IE5");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);   
        HashSet<string> extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        extensions.Add(".ico");
        extensions.Add(".jpg");
        extensions.Add(".jpeg");
        extensions.Add(".png");
        extensions.Add(".gif");
        extensions.Add(".bmp");

        string DestinationFolder2Copyfiles = @"e:\images\";
        HashSet<string> alreadyCopiedFilesHolder = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(f);
            if (extensions.Contains(ext))
            {
                string destFileName = Path.Combine(DestinationFolder2Copyfiles, Path.GetFileName(f));
                int i = 0;
                while (alreadyCopiedFilesHolder.Contains(destFileName) || System.IO.File.Exists(destFileName))
                {
                    destFileName = Path.Combine(DestinationFolder2Copyfiles, string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f), i, ext));
                    i += 1;
                }
                alreadyCopiedFilesHolder.Add(destFileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(f, destFileName);
            }
        }
```