# C# copy IE cached file?

Tags: c#

I want to copy a file with a given name from IE cache in windows 7.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Temporary Internet Files");
var files = di.GetFiles();
```

but `files` is empty, while I can see there are files in explorer, but those don't have filepath, and when copy pasted manually those change their names.

All I want to achieve is load a webpage in WebBrowserControl, have it rendered perfectly by the JS engine, and copy particular catched image without changing its filename.

Comment: This is how you should get the path, as a) it varies by OS version and b) it can be changed: `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache));`

Comment: Didn't knew abowt SpecialFolder.InternetCache. Anyway, my image is just url, but it is nowhere to be found on the filesystem as file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581094/programmatically-copy-files-from-temporary-internet-files-into-other-directory I found out why...